# Why the button is not disabling when there is no text?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react-native and when i was creating my app i couldn't get auto add button disabling to work

I set up these properties as a hooks:

```
const [taskText, setTaskText] = useState(null);  
const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState('true');
```

then i have my function:

```
const addActivity = () => {
    if (taskText == null){
      setDisabled('true');
    }else{
      setDisabled('false');
    }
  }
```

but when i use isDisabled on touchableOpacity's disable prop its not updating

textInput prop :

```
onChange={() => addActivity()}
```

TouchableOpacity:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.addWrapper} onPress={() => handleNewTask()} disabled={isDisabled}>
    <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

setTaskText: (called by TextInput)

```
onChangeText={text => setTaskText(text)}
```

Doesn't TextInput update itself when i delete all the text?
What do i do to fix this?

Comment: Where is `setTaskText` called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use : `useState('true')` and you always use a string in your state.
A string, when it is not empty, is always true.

You must use the boolean values not string. You can therefore change to : `useState(true)` and change `addActivity` to :

```
const addActivity = () => {
    if (taskText == null){
      setDisabled(true);
    }else{
      setDisabled(false);
    }
  }
```